# How to change the moderator values for a moderated mediation using Hayes Process in R

Tags: r, process

I'm using Hayes PROCESS in R to do a mediation model with a moderated direct effect (model 5). I'd like to specify values for my moderator, e.g. like you can with `modx.values = c(-1,0,1)` for simple slopes.

I haven't been able to find any arguments to specify moderator values in PROCESS, does anyone know if there is one?

The code that I'm using is the usual PROCESS code, as follows:

```
process(data=Data2EC_BR),
y="Social_Distance",
x="Mean_Mor_Con2",
m="Feat_Sit_cen",
w = "Ag_Rec_Cen",
model=5,
total=1,
effsize=1,
normal=1,
conf = 95)
```

I'm having trouble pasting some sample data in here but I shouldn't think it's needed, the code works fine I'm just after an argument I can add that can change the mod values. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I've now provided my code (although I'm just looking for an argument, not having trouble with code). Could my question please be reopened?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Where does `process` come from? Some sample of data really is necessary—right now we can't run your code because we don't have the data or any way to mimic it, don't know what packages you're using, and can't see any output